# Return of the Riley Riddles in Reverse

Tags: word, wordplay

For no reason in particular, here's one more batch of [these inverted riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22riley+riddles+in+reverse%22) from last year, where the solutions are what you'd usually use as the wordplay clues in a Riley Riddle. Here's how it goes:

> **You get three words.**
>   You must find **one solution word** that you can attach..
>
> - to the **beginning** of one of the three words, (you have to figure out which one)
> - somewhere in the **middle** of another, and
> - to the **end** of the remaining word,
>
> so that in each case, a new, single word is formed.

All the words here are very random, and some of them are even very rare, but every clue, result, and solution word is going to be strictly [valid in Scrabble](https://scrabblewordfinder.org/check).

1. **dally - can - infer**
2. **killer - bets - pa**
3. **blesses - ruff - arse**
4. **lier - reed - bar**

If you get stuck, you can combine the solutions to find a motivational phrase that may help you along.

---

<sub>*As always, any feedback and improvement suggestions will be highly appreciated. (Oh, and sorry about the "bets", I originally had "wart", but the Scrabble dictionary let me down there.)*</sub>

Comment: I say we start calling these "Bass riddles". *(runs for cover)*

Comment: @jafe YOU MONSTER

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: What @Rubio $\diamondsuit$ said. (I am only additionally commenting to ensure that Rubio's comment is not potentially overlooked.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> 1. **NO**dally - ca**NO**n - infer**NO**
>  2. **PAIN**killer - be**PAIN**ts - pa**PAIN**
>  3. **NO**blesses - ru**NO**ff - arse**NO**
>  4. **GAIN**lier - re**GAIN**ed - bar**GAIN**

Comment: it's like... *8 mins 17 secs*? wow, nicely done, +1!

Comment: Nice +1, I have to say I'm a little disappointed that the pattern was prefix-infix-suffix in each one.

Comment: @hexomino Isn't that the point of a Reilly Riddle? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Dewey823 Sorry, my point is that the first word uses the prefix, the second uses the infix and the third, the suffix. The wording of the riddle suggests that this order may have been mixed up in some of the examples.

Comment: @hexomino As long as you don't know in advance that it isn't shuffled, it shouldn't really make a difference, right? The puzzle format is originally an experiment on making easy puzzles that still feel rewarding to solve, and finding that "cheat" on the fly is one of the intended rewards. Naturally, it won't have that effect if you start by taking a peek at the solution first. :-)

Comment: @Bass Fair point.

Comment: @hexomino Got it, I see what you're saying